# Pattern match through shell scripting for FTP

Tags: shell, ftp

I am writing a shell script and need to download patches using ftp. There are various version of patches but I would like to download patches matching pattern *$ver_LINUX* or *$ver_Generic*. The mget command below will not allow me to use or (|) option for this purpose. Can anyone please suggest if this is possible in ftp and how.

```
ftp -inv $FTP <<EOF
quote USER $ftp_usr
quote PASS $ftp_pass
cd $patch
binary # for zip files.
ls # Just for check
mget  *${ver}_LINUX.* # downloads patches like p111229_1120200_Linux.zip
EOF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the classical `ftp` command, it isn't. However, you can do this with `lftp`, using the `-i` option of `mirror`.